# Tracking link clicks with loaded javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript file that I am loading for some of the pages for tracking different events. Javascript has a list of selectors and just attaches listeners to them and call a tracking api when selectors are clicked. 
Some of the elements are links. I am wondering if there is a possible case when navigation to links href will be done before the attached listener will run and call the tracking api.

Comment: Please provide some code so we can see what is possible in your case.

Comment: The problem is, that your tracking api probably makes an ajax call to the api enpoint, and if the next page loads faster than the ajax call, it will be cancelled and your tracking api wont receive the data.

Comment: @ManuelOtto, yes, exactly. I am just wondering if there is a way to avoid moving the navigation part from the link to event handler function.

Comment: Can you tell us the tracking vendor and how you are loading the library?  There may be some required setup process.

Comment: There is no tracking vendor, I am using our own API which writes received data as JSON and writes it into our own database. The tracking file is just adds the event listeners and sends data to API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this can help you, but to navigate to the URL and logging after it, would'nt this be the same as logging on each page load? You might be able to get the URL of traffic origin to trace everything.

Or, if you implement pjax, or load in new pages through ajax, you can wait for the new page to load and log the request after the loading is done.

Or, you could end up doing some voodoo like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a:not([href="#"])', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // Do logging here
   window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

(edit: oh yeah, I used jQuery...)

Comment: Thanks, looks like a possible solution. Will give a try!

Comment: Hope you get the expected results! I've got the same set-up in our app to fallback to a normal page load when ajax loading fails.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have specific selectors for the elements you bind the tracking event to, you could simply target all links with said selector, prevent the default behaviour with `preventDefault()`, call the tracking api and redirect (possible as a callback if the api call allows it) to the url in `href` property of the link.